# Can I retrofit new radiant electric heat using existing wiring from the old baseboard wiring?

Tags: electrical, baseboard, heat, retrofit

I am removing two baseboard heaters in a 12x10 room,and have two 120v quiet warmth radiant heat mats laid.  I’d like to know if I can use the old wiring if I change the old thermostat to a quietwarmth thermostat (to match the heating ma). Additionally the wiring from the thermostat reads 240v. And the breaker controls two bedrooms.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely yes, **BUT** the more important part is that the new thermostat is line voltage and not low voltage.  **AND** the over-current protection **AND** voltage is correct for the heating mat.  Both are **critically** important.  If the heating pad is 120volts and you're pumping 240 into, you'll have a BIG problem. You need to  check the specs on everything. You could probably re-use the installed wiring, but it may require a change of a breaker in the main panel.  If you are not comfortable working in a live panel....you have to be **VERY CAREFUL**, maybe it's time to call in a pro.

Comment: The thermostat wires are getting a reading of 240v . Is there a way to split up the two hot red wires coming in to make it 120v?